# I have this method to click on the recaptcha but then I can't click the login button

Tags: java, selenium, maven, intellij-idea, testng

method to click on reCaptcha:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(25));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click();
```

this is de error in the console:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for all conditions to be valid: presence of element located by: By.id: //*[@id="b-login-submit"] && visibility of element located by By.id: //*[@id="b-login-submit"] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

to click on the login button

Comment: I suggest running your selenium code non-headless so that you can see what is happening in the browser.

Comment: I already run the case and it's work fine

Comment: If the button is clickable immediately remove the second wait.